# Calling a method on a View Controller from another View Controller's Subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

Here is my current setup:

- CalendarViewController

  - reloadCalendar()
- SideMenuViewController

  - SideMenuView

    - toggleEventsBtn

Here is some of my code inside `SideMenuView`:

```
toggleEventsBtn.addTarget(self, action: "toggleButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
func toggleButton(sender: MenuControlButton!) {
    let shouldShowEvents = sender.shouldShowEvents
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(shouldShowEvents, forKey: "ShowEvents")
}
```

After this code runs, I need it to call the `reloadCalendar` method on `CalendarViewController`. What's the best way to accomplish something like this?

Also, is it bad practice that I'm updating `NSUserDefaults` from within a `UIView`?

All help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: create a delegate/protocol in your `CalendarViewController` which will be called in your `toggleEventsBtn`

Comment: I think NSNotificationCenter will do the trick.

Comment: What about the calling of `NSUserDefaults` from within the subview? Is that a bad practice/ should be moved to the ViewController?

Comment: And is there a difference/ advantage in me using delegate/protocols over NSNotificationCenter? @Rajatp

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927965/nsnotificationcenter-vs-delegation-using-protocols